# Running exe built in VC++ on XP and WIN7

Tags: visual-c++, windows-7, windows-xp

sprintf_s(cmd, "%c:\index.exe", driver);

I am trying to run a flash file, the application is built in VS 2008 , on win 7. The application works well on WIN7 but fails in XP. Ie the application launches but doesn't complete the task. I see the application running in Task Manager

Comment: So you already asked seven questions and none of the answers were accepted. Either you haven't taken the time to properly understand how SO works, or you're asking questions in a way that yields no acceptable answer. Both is bad if you want people to help you.

Comment: You deleted all the code apart form one line ? Was that intentional ?

Comment: Agree with Paul here, you should provide as much information as possible so that others can understand the actual problems, before they can offer anything. One 'sprintf_s' statement hardly tells me anything.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would hazard a guess that `exitcode` in your while loop is always non-zero so you're just going round an infinite loop.